# How to run Spring Boot service from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, spring-boot

I am trying to run  a Spring Boot service from Android Studio. How should I set up my 'Run Configuration' in android studio?

[image]

The above is my current configuration.

Comment: I was bumping to this old question of mine. If it helps any one: my problem at the time was I had a spring boot Backend and Android Frontend, and wanted to edit them in the same project. for me the simple solution was to change the IDE to IntelJ. Since Android-studio is based on it - it is almost similar and has the Android plugins to make it function with Android needs.